# How to get data based on row count in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project where I have to fetch data from database if the row count is greater than zero then show it otherwise don't. But my query returning all rows.

This is My Query

```sql
SELECT
    d.id,
    d.district,
    (
    SELECT
        COUNT(a.district_id)
    FROM
        ambulance AS a
    WHERE
        a.district_id = d.id
) AS total
FROM
    district d
ORDER BY
    total
DESC
```

That is okay, but I added a `WHERE` clause with my query witch is,

```sql
WHERE total > 0
```

But I am having a sql error **Unknown column 'total' in 'where clause'**

Now my question is, how can I achieve a result with `WHERE total > 0`, do I have to type something else in the place of total? What is the proper way to add this `WHERE` clause in my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL extends the use of the `HAVING` clause, so it can be used in non-aggregation queries.  This allows you to use an alias:

```
SELECT d.id, d.district,
      (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM ambulance a
       WHERE a.district_id = d.id
      ) AS total
FROM district d
HAVING total > 0
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

This logic would more colloquially be written using an inner join:

```
select d.id, d.district, count(*) as total
from district d join
     ambulance a
     on a.district_id = d.id
group by d.id, d.district 
order by total desc;
```

The `join` requires that there be at least one match.